# ColumnHeaderContainerStyle FontFamily

Tags: .net, wpf, gridview

How can I set the FontFamily on a ColumnHeaderContainerStyle?
The follow two both set the FontStyle and FontSize properly but fail on FontFamily

```
<GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="18"/>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontFamily" Value="Wingdings"/> <!--Segoe UI Symbol-->
    </Style>
</GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>

<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="28"/>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontFamily" Value="Wingdings"/>
        <!--Segoe UI Symbol-->
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

content is set in code behind

```
GridViewColumnHeader gvch = (GridViewColumnHeader)gv.Columns[colNum].Header;
gvch.Content = gvch.Content + glyphAscStr;
```

Comment: the first snippet seems to work on my side. The ***I*** letter is rendered as a hand. I guess on your side there is some square rendered instead. Also I've tried it in a simple WPF desktop demo if it matters.

Comment: @KingKing Wow, thanks, there must be something about my environment that is messing things up.  I am setting the content in code behind as  I am building the columns dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a better answer I will give it a check
According to King King the code in the question works
Most likely something in my environment is messing it up
And it might be because I am setting the content via code behind binding
This is how I got it to work

```
<GridView>
    <GridView.ColumnHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TbSymbol}" Margin="6,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <Binding/>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ColumnHeaderTemplate>
```